# How to get good images for Graph in Published Notebooks

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, wolfram-cloud, antialiasing, publishing

Consider the following `Graph` as an example:

```
Graph[
    {"Square"->"Rectangle","Rectangle"->"Parallelogram","Parallelogram"->"Four-Sided Polygon","Trapezoid"->"Four-Sided Polygon","Rectangle"->"Trapezoid","Four-Sided Polygon"->"Polygon","Polygon"->"Shape","Circle"->"Ellipsoid","Ellipsoid"->"Shape","Triangle"->"Polygon","Equilateral Triangle"->"Isosceles Triangle","Isosceles Triangle"->"Triangle"},
    PlotTheme->"DiagramGreen",

    VertexSize->{.4,.15},
    VertexLabelStyle->Directive[FontFamily->"Arial",FontSize->14],
    AspectRatio->1.5,
    ImageSize->Large
]
```

The image is sharp and crisp (or at least bearable) in the local notebook.

[image]

But if I publish it to the cloud and look at it there, it is of low quality.

[image]

It may not look that bad in this simple diagram but for a more complex diagram with many branches, the vertexes are small and become unreadable and diagonal or curved edges are breaking off (aliasing).

Moreover, the case becomes severe if I am trying to convey information by using a vertex shape function with different types of dotted edges (it becomes difficult to distinguish with the aliasing happening in the cloud):

```
VertexShapeFunction->(Inset[Framed[#2,
    Background->...change based on #2 ...,
    FrameStyle->Directive[...change based on #2 to {Black,Dotted}, {Black,DotDashed} or {Black,Dashed}...]
],#1]&)
```

Finally, what happens to the hyperlinks in the vertexes of the `Graph` in the cloud published notebook, they just don't want to work!

```
Graph[
    {"Square"->"Rectangle","Rectangle"->"Parallelogram","Parallelogram"->"Four-Sided Polygon","Trapezoid"->"Four-Sided Polygon","Rectangle"->"Trapezoid","Four-Sided Polygon"->"Polygon","Polygon"->"Shape","Circle"->"Ellipsoid","Ellipsoid"->"Shape","Triangle"->"Polygon","Equilateral Triangle"->"Isosceles Triangle","Isosceles Triangle"->"Triangle"}/.{
        "Rectangle"->Hyperlink["Rectangle","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle"]
    },
    PlotTheme->"DiagramGreen",

    VertexSize->{.4,.15},
    VertexLabelStyle->Directive[FontFamily->"Arial",FontSize->14],
    AspectRatio->1.5,
    ImageSize->Large
]
```

Comment: the problem partly solved see here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215016/how-to-fix-the-legend-and-dotted-edges-in-wolframcloud

Comment: Don’t use cloud publishing, just export to markdown with Kuba’s package and convert to html

Comment: @M.R. can you provide a link to Kuba's package. Does it work with graphs elements and will it be able to convert complex graphs including `Epilog` to HTML (see the example of graph I drew on the other [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215016/how-to-fix-the-legend-and-dotted-edges-in-wolframcloud))? Also, can I host this generated HTML on the wolfram cloud? Because I don't have a website of my own and was looking to host on wolfram cloud so I can share using the wolfram cloud link.