# How to fix the legend and dotted edges in WolframCloud?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, wolfram-cloud, antialiasing, publishing

Following the problems in my previous question:

[How to get good images for Graph in Published Notebooks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214715/how-to-get-good-images-for-graph-in-published-notebooks)

I found a way to fix the aliasing issue, apparently, the `Graph` doesn't have automatic `Antialiasing` in wolfram cloud so I have to convert it into `Graphics` then use explicit `Antialiasing` but this introduced another set of problems.

Following the same example in my last question for illustration:

```
$diagram=Graph[
    {"Square"->"Rectangle","Rectangle"->"Parallelogram","Parallelogram"->"Four-Sided Polygon","Trapezoid"->"Four-Sided Polygon","Rectangle"->"Trapezoid","Four-Sided Polygon"->"Polygon","Polygon"->"Shape","Circle"->"Ellipsoid","Ellipsoid"->"Shape","Triangle"->"Polygon","Equilateral Triangle"->"Isosceles Triangle","Isosceles Triangle"->"Triangle"}/.{
        "Rectangle"->Hyperlink["Rectangle","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle"],
        "Square"->Hyperlink["Square","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square"]
    },

    EdgeShapeFunction->({
        Black,Opacity[1],
        GraphElementData[{"ShortUnfilledArrow","ArrowSize"->0.01,"ArrowPositions"->0.5}]@##
    }&),

    VertexShapeFunction->(Inset[Framed[#2,Background->LightYellow,FrameStyle->Directive[If[Head@#2===Hyperlink,If[First@#2=="Square",{Black,Dotted},{Black,Dashed}],{Black,DotDashed}]]],#1]&),

    GraphLayout->{"LayeredDigraphEmbedding","Orientation"->Left},
    AspectRatio->0.4,
    ImageSize->{700,300},

    Epilog->Inset[Column[{
        LineLegend[
            (Directive[DeleteDuplicates[{Black,#}]]&/@{Dotted,DotDashed,Dashed,Black}),
            Range[4]
        ]
    }],{-0.5,1.5}]
]
```

[image]

```
Style[Show@$diagram,Antialiasing->True]
```

[image]

Hopefully you can see that the different types of dotted edges have been turned into simply dotted. Secondly my legend epiloged onto the graph has been destroyed.

I am just looking for a workaround if someone could find it so I can published my desired graph in the cloud notebook for sharing. Thanks!

Comment: do you get what you need if you use `EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Antialiasing -> True, Black, Opacity[1], 
    GraphElementData[{"ShortUnfilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> 0.01, 
       "ArrowPositions" -> 0.5}]@##} &)`?

Comment: @kglr nope nothing is changing by introducing option `Antialiasing->True` in the `EdgeShapeFunction`. I finally thought published wolfram cloud notebooks might resolve the issue of sharing notebooks online with people who don't have a wolfram license (at least as a webpage) but wolfram cloud formatting is way undercooked compared to the local front-end.

Comment: how about adding `BaseStyle -> Antialiasing  -> True` in `Graph[...]`?

Comment: @kglr nope `BaseStyle ->Antialiasing -> True` as a option for `Graph` brings no change.

Comment: If WRI don't put their act together and make cloud notebooks work just like or better than their local version, they will lose their lead on the notebook end as well since big players like Microsoft and Google are incorporating Jupyter into their own platform with [Azure Notebook](https://notebooks.azure.com/) and [Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks) respectively and with far better computational power on offer.

Comment: Ok Jupyter notebooks are even detaching themselves away from the browser into a [local version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_C0vbLV6WdA) through products like VSCode.